# Knockoutjs 1.3.0 beta control flow binding foreach

Tags: knockout.js

I am having a very hard time using the foreach control flow binding in my project.

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/mbynum/YVVbg/

Summery of Fiddler:

Javascript:

```
var viewModel = {
    Chart: {
        Name: "something"
    },
    VarsOptions: ko.observableArray([{
        Name: "test1"},
    {
        Name: "Test2"}])
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Something?</h1>
<ul data-bind:"foreach: VarsOptions">
    <li data-bind="text: Name"></li>
</ul>
```

I am referencing the knockout: http://cloud.github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-1.3.0beta.js
from github:
https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/downloads

I have seen people on fiddler get this to work. I dont see how my code is different or why it might not be working. I am beginning to believe it might be the way I am setting up my javascript object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your issue:

```
<ul data-bind:"foreach: VarsOptions">
```

Should be:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: VarsOptions">
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!! I cant believe I missed that. I even had my coworkers looking at this with me.